# How to make a jButton change it's color when all the options are selected?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

Hello everyone :) I want my `JButton` to change it's color when all the options are selected but I don't know how...

I have a `ButtonGroup` for 6 Radio Buttons, 6 Check Boxes, and a Text Field

When a radio button is selected AND one or more check boxes are selected AND the text field has a number in it (or anything), the `JButton` changes it's color to green. I don't know where to put the action listener or how to begin, so if anyone is nice enough to help me, I would be very grateful.

Ok, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104631/i-want-to-display-a-message-showing-what-i-selected-java) some of the code, as you asked, but I don't think it's relevant. Essentially, this is a continuation of my previous question.

Comment: You should show some code illustrating what you've already put together.  Otherwise, you're essentially asking for someone to write your form handler.

Comment: You add the ActionListener to any and all things that needs to be selected for the JButton to be active. The listener will check that all things that need to be selected are selected. I suggest that rather than setting the JButton's background color which is fraught with look and feel issues, you instead change the JButton's enabled state via `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` method.

Comment: +1 for the `setEnabled` suggestion of @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 3):

If you simply have a method that adjust the color of the button based on the state of the buttons and the text field, e.g.

```
public void updateButtonColor(){
  if ( isAtLeastOneRadioButtonSelected() && isAtLeastOneCheckBoxSelected() && 
       textFieldContainsNumber() ){
      changeButtonColor( Color.green );
   } else {
      changeButtonColor( Color.red );
   }
}
```

you can add listeners to each of the radio buttons, check boxes and text field to call that `updateButtonColor` method when the relevant state of the component changes (e.g. an `ItemListener` to the `JCheckBox` to detect changes in selection)

Comment: @AlejandraUzelac The [Swing button tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) has examples of how attaching listeners to those, and those listeners could then call that method

Comment: I've put the isAtLeastOneRadioButtonSelected (isRadioSelected) and so on as a boolean, for the radio buttons I've put an ItemStateChanged event:
`if (jRadioButton1.isSelected())
        {
            isRadioSelected=true;
            updateButtonColor();
        }
`
For the check boxes also and ItemStateChanged event with the code:
`if (checkbox1.getState()==true)
        {
            isChecked=true;
            updateButtonColor();
        }
`
I get an error but it still works, but I can't figure out how to check if the jTextBox has text in it... which event should I use?

Comment: @AlejandraUzelac `DocumentListener`s are the ones which get updated when text is entered/removed/... from a text field

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and there is no DocumentListener - http://s15.postimage.org/i7vd48pcr/Untitled.png